# power query - How to limit rows extracted from a Progress Database

Tags: rows, powerquery, openedge, progress-db

I am connected to a Progress OpenHedge Dadabase though ODBC. I want to limit the number of records extracted but I cannot figure where to put the sql code.
sample code reads as follows:

```
Source = Odbc.DataSource("dsn=ODBCMXP", [HierarchicalNavigation=true]),
abcd_Database = Source{[Name="abcd",Kind="Database"]}[Data],
PUB_Schema = abcd_Database{[Name="PUB",Kind="Schema"]}[Data],
#"invoice-line_Table" = PUB_Schema{[Name="invoice-line",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
```

I would like to limit records to Documentnumber > 10000 for example or DocumentDate > "2022-01-01" for example.. the same problems arise on other tables where millions of rows are read and need to be filtered out after and thus increasing update time.
Help with the query code would be appraciated !

Comment: Use `Odbc.Query` rather than `Odbc.DataSource` if you want to supply a query instead of navigating to a table. Note that you can also filter the data on the PowerQuery end, and if the data source supports folding, the condition may be interpolated into a query automagically. I don't know if it works in this case, though.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen I will investigate that route. Regards Jacques